# Why is Tomcat not reserving minimum heap space

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, heap-memory

I am running `Tomcat` 6 on Linux and set Xms and Xmx in setenv.sh. After starting the `Tomcat` server I don't see the memory usage increased by at least specified in Xms.

Before startup    `free -m` is showing 1500 as free memory.

In my `startup.sh` I can see memory settings.

```
CATALINA_OPTS:  -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

After server startup `free -m` is showing 1140 as free memory. Why free memory is not reduced by at least 512m?

```
jinfo 14064 is showing VM Flags: -Xms512m -Xmx1024m

jmap -heap is also showing memory settings are applied
```

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   **MaxHeapSize      = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)**

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: which IDE you are using?

Comment: I am not using any IDE. The Apps is already deployed on Tomcat on Linus. I am just trying to increase memory.

Answer (score 0):

free -m command

http://www.linuxtoday.com/upload/understanding-free-command-in-linuxunix-130530185004.html

This command will show Actual free RAM.
RAM memory and Virtual memory are different. 
Actual initial heap size and max heap size can be allocation by heap 
could be identified with the following command.
add  the following  jvm argument -verbose:gc
and restart the server. Once the server is restarted and  after initialization the verbose logs shows the following

// attribute name="maxHeapSize" value="0x40000000"

//attribute name="initialHeapSize" value="0x20000000"

Converting the value into the MB it will show the  Xms and Xmx  allocation.

Above shown is the snippet of the following command
java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -verbose:gc -version

Comment: Nice explanation on how these are differentiated.